# jar class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I am working in Spring MVC, and was given an executable jar file with few classes and to add in my project.

I added that jar using build path as external jar.

Then I used a class in that jar file to call a method which returns a string.

I am getting error in maven install

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] com/mmf/controllers/myprojectController.java:[12,0] The import com.canonical.client.myClass cannot be resolved
    [ERROR] com/mmf/controllers/myprojectController.java:[31,0] myClass cannot be resolved to a type
    [ERROR] com/mmf/controllers/myprojectController.java:[31,0] myClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: We need further details like pom.xml and your directory structure please? Is com.canonical.* owned by you?

Comment: No, Its from that jar file I got. I add that using build path. thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the external JAR file to your Maven project, you need to run the below command before you do `mvn install`.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<actual path for the intended jar file> -DgroupId=<group_id>  -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version of jar file> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

For example,

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:\something.jar  -DgroupId=someGroupId -DartifactId=someArtifactId -Dversion=someVersion -Dpackaging=jar
```

This step is required to be carried out only once. After you do this, the required JAR file will be added to the local maven repository and from next time onward, it will be used when you do `mvn install`.

Comment: Now I am using that jar from lib folder and deleted it from build path.

Comment: After running the command I shared, did it give any error? If not, just verify in your local repository, if the intended jar is present. Also, make sure that the JAR is also present in `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your jar is not available while building.

You can include the external jars in your build path as maven dependency with system

Eg :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/platform-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).